Make TextField's hover effect area bigger in VisionOS
Is it possible to make TextField's hover effect area bigger? Adding padding doesn't seem to work.
TextField(placeholder, text: $text)
    .padding()




TextField("Placeholder", text: $text)
    .hoverEffectDisabled() //  Disable the original hover effect
    .padding()
    .background()
    .hoverEffect() //  Add a custom hover effect


Very slick approach!

To build on @Mojtaba's answer, here is a complete solution that replicates the screenshot in the original question, and make the entire hover area tappable.
@FocusState private var textFieldFocused: Bool

HStack(alignment: .center) {
  TextField("Add a comment", text: $comment, axis: .vertical)
     .hoverEffectDisabled()
     .focused($textFieldFocused)
  Button("Send", systemImage: "arrow.up") {}
    .controlSize(.small)
    .labelStyle(.iconOnly)
    .buttonStyle(.borderless)
}
.padding()
.contentShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 32))
.hoverEffect()
.glassBackgroundEffect()
.onTapGesture {
     textFieldFocused = true
  }
}


You can use padding to make it larger. And use contentShape property to make  the shape of the Hover. Like this:
Text("Totle Count")
.padding(10)
.contentShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerSize: CGSizeMake(20, 20)))
.hoverEffect()

